# Jquery in Wordpress won't work on find toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, find, toggle

My toggle won't work in wordpress but it works perfectly in HTML
This is my script:

```
$(".enkeltopslag").on("click", function () { 
   $(this).find(".opslaginfo").fadeToggle(200); 
   $(this).find(".jobregister").fadeToggle(200); 
   $(this).find(".opslagtitel").toggleClass("opslagbg");
});
```

Comment: did you enqueue jquery properly?

Comment: there could be tons of reasons why this code is not working. There are not these elements in the page, there are not these elements when you execute this script, you are not enqueuing this script properly, etc... That's impossible to say in this way. It would be already great to know what "won't work" means. Error in the console? The code is not executed? ...?